# What is the use of Mercury and Tomcat in Xampp control panel?

Tags: xampp

Recently I installed Xampp server.

I know apache is used to run php server scripts and MySQL is used for database actions and FileZilla for transfering files to web to server.

But I don't understand what the Mercury and Tomcat Modules are for, can some explain?

Comment: Here are some Wikipedia links for easy reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_Mail_Transport_System, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat

Answer (score 42):

**Mercury :**

> Its a package to send emails. Its a local mail server.

[image: Mercury in action]

**Tomcat :**

> The Apache Tomcat software is an open source implementation of the
> Jakarta Servlet, Jakarta Server Pages, Jakarta Expression Language and Jakarta
> WebSocket technologies.

[Tomcat official website](https://tomcat.apache.org)

[Getting Started with Tomcat](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FrontPage)

**XAMPP Control Panel with Modules :**

[image: XAMPP's Control Panel]